# Obtener los valores máximo-minimo de una columna en función del id en la otra columna

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

Como obtener el valor máximo y mínimo de cada id reflejado en una de las columnas de un array 2d con numpy sin múltiples bucles, es decir, sin hacer una máscara por cada id dentro de un for y hacer el max-min.

Ejemplo de array2 np.array([[valor, id], ..., [valor, id]]):

```
[
[1, 1]
[6, 4]
[2, 2]
[3, 1]
[5, 3]
[5, 1]
[3, 2]
]

Resultado deseado => array: [5, 3, 5, 6]

# para el id:1 => 5
# para el id:2 => 3
# para el id:3 => 5
# etc
```

### Edito para clarificar:

Se pretende obtener un array 1d con el valor máximo por cada conjunto perteneciente a una misma id

### Edito 2:

Sé que se puede obtener mediante un bucle for recorriendo cada id, realizando una máscaras por cada una de ellas y aplicando cada máscara independientemente a np.max. Pero esta forma es altamente costosa e ineficiente en comparación con cualquier mecanismo que pudiese presentar numpy de forma optimizada.

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. Debes traducir tu pregunta al castellano, ya que es el idioma oficial de este sitio, de lo contrario tu pregunta terminará cerrada. Saludos

Comment: También podrías haber preguntado en [StackOveflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) (el sito en ingles).

Comment: @Dante S. pues precisamente la cuenta me la cree en el sitio en ingles pero imagino que por idioma del navegador acabé redirigido aquí sin ser consciente de que fuesen distintas comunidades. En cualquier caso, la pregunta estaba ya editada y traducida a perfecto español ;)

Comment: Curioso! Yo igual te lo proponía por si te sentías mejor preguntando en el otro sitio. Quizá te sentís más cómodo preguntando en ingles que en español.

Comment: Pues todo lo contrario señor, me siento muchísimo más cómodo preguntando en la lengua natal pero soy consciente de la diferencia tan abismal de usuarios angloparlantes frente a los hispanoparlantes y precisamente teniendo en cuenta el índole de la pregunta en cuestión me resulta cuando menos "curioso" la distinción entre ambas, pero esto es otro tema

Comment: Disculpa no entendí bien la pregunta, solo muestras un array pero tu pones el resultado de varios, lo cual es muy confuso

Comment: @Christian Encantado te respondo y explico qué estoy mostrando: Expongo un array 2d formado por 7 filas y 2 columnas, el primer índice de cada fila es un valor y el segundo índice es una id. Lo que pretendo es tener un array con el valor máximo perteneciente a cada id, muestro el array 1d que deseo tener, que es el valor máximo escogido fijándote únicamente entre los valores que poseen la misma id.

Answer (score 0):

No sé si te entendí bien, creo que quieres obtener el valor máximo de cada numpy array según el valor del `id`, que es la segunda columna (o segundo elemento), para esto te puedes apoyar de la función `max()` propia de Python.

Creé otro array para probar.

```
array1 = np.array([[1, 1],
                   [6, 4],
                   [2, 2],
                   [3, 1],
                   [5, 3],
                   [5, 1],
                   [3, 2]])

array2 = np.array([[2, 3],
                   [3, 1],
                   [8, 2],
                   [3, 2],
                   [7, 8],
                   [3, 2],
                   [1, 2]])

max_arr1 = max(array1, key=lambda x: x[1])
max_arr2 = max(array2, key=lambda x: x[1])

print(max_arr1)
print(max_arr2)
```

Como resultado obtendremos todo el array donde el segundo elemento sea el mayor, en comparación al resto.
**resultado**

```
[6 4]
[7 8]
```

Si solo quieres el segundo elemento solo tienes que acceder a tal, de esta forma `max(array1, key=lambda x: x[1])[1]`

Pero supongamos que tienes un array con todos estos *arrays* pues en ese caso puedes usar la función `map()`, también propia de Python, la cual permite aplicarle una operación a cada elemento y el resultado será el de la operación

Basándonos en los arrays anteriores

```py
arrays = np.array((array1,array2))

#recorremos los arrays
resultado = list(map(lambda arr: max(arr, key=lambda x: x[1])[1], arrays))
```

A la función `map()` le pasamos una lmabda, función anónima, que recibe como parámetro un array (variable `arr`), el cual es cada array de la variable `arrays` y a ese array le aplica la función `max`, que ya la explique arriba. Como `map` es una *built-in function* el resultado es un dato del mismo tipo, por lo que habrá que transformarlo a una lista con `list()`
**resultado**

```
[4, 8]
```

El resultado es el segundo elemento (el `id` mayor) de cada uno de los *arrays*, esto por que especificamos obtener el segundo con `max(arr, key=lambda x: x[1])[1]` (con el `[1]` al final). `numpy` también tiene una función para hallar el máximo, pero no estoy muy familiarizado con eso, pero puedes investigar y adaptar mi solución.

Answer (score 0):

Hay algunas formas de resolverlo directamente sobre el `array` pero son algo complejas, sin embargo si convertimos el mismo en un dataframe, podemos usar `pandas` para agrupar y sumar:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

arr = np.array([
[1, 1],
[6, 4],
[2, 2],
[3, 1],
[5, 3],
[5, 1],
[3, 2]
])


df = pd.DataFrame(arr, columns=["valor", "id"])

df.groupby("id").valor.max().to_numpy()
df.groupby("id").valor.min().to_numpy()

[5 3 5 6]
[1 2 5 6]
```